# how to django form takes a request

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have some problem. I wanna take a request in django forms but it may have some problem. here is my code.
forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    CHOICES = request.user.fields()
    receive_user = fields.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
    content = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget(show_preview=False))
    publish = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
        "receive_user",
        "content",
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and views.py

```
def post_create(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        raise Http404

    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request=request)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
```

and error message is

NameError: name 'request' is not defined

Comment: Please edit your question to post the full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request` is passed to the `__init__` method and is therefore only available there. You can't use it at module level because it's not defined there; and you wouldn't want to, anyway, because anything at module level is run once when the class is first imported, not when the form is instantiated.

But since you do have it within init, you should use it there:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    receive_user = fields.MultipleChoiceField(choices=())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['receive_user'].choices = request.user.....
```

(Note, I doubt that `.fields()` is what you want there, but never mind.)

Comment: thanks!! self.fields['receive_user'].choices = self.request.user.... is working!!:)